# What C++11 features does Visual Studio 2010 support?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c++11

There is [a list](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) for GCC; is there a similar list for Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There is also [a list for Visual C++ 2010](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2010/04/06/c0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table/) (that article describes the core language features that have been implemented; the PDF linked from the article describes the library features that have been implemented).

**Edit:** I've just come across an awesome list:  the Apache C++ Standard Library wiki has [**a table listing the C++11 core language features**](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) and which C++ compilers support each of them.

Comment: That table is broken, you can't see the VC10 column :/

Comment: @Andreas:  Yeah, the new MSDN blogs layout broke it... I guess you can just go by the colors :-).

Comment: @T.E.D: reduce your screen resolution to e.g. 1280x800 and you will see that it IS broken.

Comment: [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) compares C++11 etc feature support in all Visual Studio versions.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the best list IMO since it breaks it down into several tabs like core language, library, etc:
[Summary of C++0x Feature Availability in gcc and MSVC](http://www.aristeia.com/C++0x/C++0xFeatureAvailability.htm)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a comprehensive [list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh567368.aspx) of C++11/14/17 support in Visual Studio 10, 12, 13, 15.

Comment: Well, that's the problem with SO. In 2010, the accepted answer might have been best. But in 2017, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

The [What's new in Visual C++ 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465215.aspx) MSDN page summarises the new feature support as well.

Answer (score 1):

See the [C++ compilers implementation matrix](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support). The page is maintained as best-effort and may lag behind most recent compiler releases.