# replacing boost:: mutex

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost

I have a program with this code:

```
mutable boost::condition_variable cvRun;

void CAteEngineInternal::RunSync()
{
    boost::mutex m;
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m);
    Run();
    //wait for run to complete
    cvRun.wait(lock);
}

int  CAteEngineInternal::RunXSync(int FramesToRun)
{
    boost::mutex m;
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m);
    int retVal = RunX(FramesToRun);
    //wait for run to complete
    cvRun.wait(lock);
    return retVal;
}


void CAteEngineInternal::OnRunCompleted(int /* status */)
{
    cvRun.notify_all();
}
```

i'm working with CLI and i'm getting the following Error:

basic_timed_mutex.hpp(216): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler

I would like to replace this boost::mutex code and find a way to overcome this complier error. i'm wokring with C# on VS2012 and C++ on VS2010. the CLI is on VS2010 as well.

any suggestions what to use ? i need it to be cross-platform, and able to compile it in VS2010.

Comment: The STL has no concurrent programming library. Neither does the C++ standard library pre-C++11.

Comment: Are you using the most recent version of Boost?

Comment: Which version of boost are you using?

Comment: i'm using boost X64 1.52

Comment: 1. Where is the [tag:c#] relevance? 2. Can you use [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and friends from [tag:c++11]?

Comment: @Johnsyweb i'm trying to compile it as VS2010 project. so no C++11. the question is about the error basic_timed_mutex.hpp(216): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler

Comment: @Androidy does the error message refer to a line of your code? Or does it happen when you include one of the boost headers?

Comment: I see the [tag:c#] tag has been removed (although it is still mentioned in the question). I'm afraid I don't recall which [tag:c++0x] features were implemented with each compiler but knew that [VS2010 at least implemented some of them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936757/what-c11-features-does-visual-studio-2010-support).

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin no, it refers to a line inbasic_timed_mutex.hpp(216): it's a boost function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem in the past while mixing VS2012 and VS2010, 
you really shouldn't work like this. it's a bug trap.

after two days of searching i have found this solution
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/753623/fatal-error-c1001

please make sure you understand how to use pragma correctly.
i was able to compile and run!

hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Off-topic, but, please note, that you are not waiting on the condition variable correctly: you should associate state (boolean in this case) with it and wait in a loop. Otherwise your code may miss a condition notification and hang forever, or receive a spurious wake-up and finish the wait prematurely. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref