# Declare array in function call

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010

Right, I KNOW this is possible in C++0x/C++11, and therefore can be done in Visual Studio 2012.

HOWEVER, I am running Visual Studio 2010.  I want to know if it is at all possible to do something similar to:

```
void MyFunction(int myArray[])
{}
```

`MyFunction({1,2,3});`

Without the inconvenience of having to declare the array beforehand.

Is there any workaround way of doing this in the version of C++ Visual Studio 2010 uses?  Or somehow updating the compiler Visual Studio 2010 uses to support more C++11 features?  Or am I out of options?

### **EDIT:**

**Thanks to yzt, I have been able to do this with Boost!**

Here's some example code in case anyone else happens to be in my position (I don't seem to be able to use a normal array with this, but an `std::vector` (or indeed another stl container), etc will do just fine!):

The function:

```
void TestFunction(std::vector<int> myArray)
{
    for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < myArray.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout<<myArray[i]<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Calling it:

`TestFunction(boost::assign::list_of(1)(2)(3));`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What C++11 features does Visual Studio 2010 support?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936757/what-c11-features-does-visual-studio-2010-support)

Comment: why is [this](http://ideone.com/V860Vn) not working?

Comment: This is not supported in VC11 (VS2012) either, but it *is* available in VC12 (VS2013 Preview.)

Comment: I seem to remember that Boost had a library for something in this ballpark (assigning to STL containers.)

Comment: I didn't know this. In C#, you can do something like `int[] a = new int[]{1, 2, 3};`, but not in C++!?

Comment: @JosuéMolina In C++11, you can do `int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };` which is even easier and a stack variable.

Comment: @anthony-arnold and works in VC10.

Comment: @anthony-arnold I do not feel this is a duplicate, I was aware that this is a C++11 feature, and not available in Visual Studio 2010's C++ compiler, I was asking if there was an equivalent way in Visual Studio 2010, which it seems there is, in Boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your exact use case, but you probably can use [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/assign/) to do this. And yes, it does work in VC10.

As has been posted in the comments, one can do like this:

```
TestFunction(boost::assign::list_of(1)(2)(3));
```

Comment: `TestFunction(boost::assign::list_of(1)(2)(3));` THANK YOU! :D

Answer (score 2):

The only version (yet) of Visual C++ to support this directly is the Visual C++ 2013 Preview.

If you're *really* set on doing this, you can define an vector_builder class that *will* let you do the job in one line -- with a few provisos: first that it pretty much *does* have to be a vector instead of an array, and second that the syntax to do the job is *quite* ugly and counter-intuitive (to the point that I hesitate to even mention it at all).

```
template<class T>
class make_vector {
    std::vector<T> data;
public:
    make_vector(T const &val) { 
        data.push_back(val);
    }

    make_vector<T> &operator,(T const &t) {
        data.push_back(t);
        return *this;
    }

    operator std::vector<T>() { return data; }
};

template<class T> 
make_vector<T> makeVect(T const &t) { 
    return make_vector<T>(t);
}
```

With this, you'd call something like:

```
MyFunction((makeVect(1),2,3));
```

As I said, this strikes me as ugly enough that I hesitate to mention it at all -- but you may prefer it to the available alternatives.

Comment: I think there is a single extra open parenthesis in your sample usage code (before `1`.) It should be `((makeVect(1),2,3))`, I believe.

Comment: Plus 1 for pointing out how ugly this type of coding style is.

Answer (score 0):

The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx) outlining C++11 support in Visual Studio states that [initialiser lists](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2672.htm) are not supported in VC10 *or* VC11.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in Visual Studio 2010, or in 2012, for that matter.  Sorry!