# Missing Library: <chrono> in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include, c++-chrono

I am trying to use the `<chrono>` library on a c++ program in visual studio 2010. I have not made any adjustments to any of the default VS2010 settings.

Upon including `chrono`:

```
#include <chrono>
```

I get the error:

> Error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'chrono': No such file or directory.

Researching this seems to suggest that it should be in VS2010, and other people experiencing my issue have been using older versions. Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Edit: I read the original conclusion here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/956dbe48-9aad-4c50-9e60-75623ac816fb/mersenne-twister?forum=vcgeneral

In future I shall check MSDN!

Comment: VS2010 is simply too old. `<chrono>` was invented after that compiler shipped.

Comment: Where did you read that this should be in VS2010? The [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874757%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `chrono` is not available for VS2010, so I doubt it is available.

Comment: See this answer for a link to a list of features: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936757/what-c11-features-does-visual-studio-2010-support

Comment: @graham.reeds Some of the links are dead (in particular the first link of the accepted answer). And none of the table-likes features list mention `chrono` or others standard library features unfortunately.

Comment: Get VS2015 if you want to use modern C++ with a Microsoft compiler. The older ones lack too much functionality and have too many standard related bugs to really be usable IMHO.

Comment: I use 2015 at home, but I'm at work :(